# Mockito: combine @Autowired and @Mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito, powermockito

I have this junit test using Mockito (an open source testing framework for Java released under the MIT License) in a The Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework application

I have this test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DeviceCatalogueControllerTest {


    @InjectMocks
    private DeviceCatalogueController controller;

    @InjectMocks
    protected SessionHelper sessionHelper;

    @Mock
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Mock
    protected CataloqueService cataloqueService;

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationDao applicationDao;

    @Before
    public void setUpTest() {
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitFormGet() throws Exception {

        System.out.println  ("SessionHelper sessionHelper --> " + sessionHelper);

        //controller.initFormGet(searchForm, localeParam, request, response, model, locale)
        controller.initFormGet(null, DEFAULT_LOCALE, request, response, null, new Locale(DEFAULT_LOCALE));
        }
```

but when running the test **applicationDao** is null

Comment: Why wouldn't it be `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test class is totally unaware of the `Spring`. To use `Spring` in unit tests you have to use the correct annotation `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` instead of the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` you are using now.

Then in the `@Before` method you can initialize your `Mockito` mocks by calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Your test class can be re-coded as:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/application-context.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DeviceCatalogueControllerTest {


    @InjectMocks
    private DeviceCatalogueController controller;

    @InjectMocks
    protected SessionHelper sessionHelper;

    @Mock
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Mock
    protected CataloqueService cataloqueService;

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationDao applicationDao;

    @Before
    public void setUpTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitFormGet() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("SessionHelper sessionHelper --> " + sessionHelper);

        //controller.initFormGet(searchForm, localeParam, request, response, model, locale)
        controller.initFormGet(null, DEFAULT_LOCALE, request, response, null, new Locale(DEFAULT_LOCALE));
    }
}
```

Note: use the correct xml path for your `application-context.xml` in `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/application-context.xml"})`